# How to compute $\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}(\frac{\sin x}{x})^2(\frac{\sin ax}{ax})^2dx, a>0$?

Tags: calculus, fourier-transform

> How to compute $\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}(\frac{\sin x}{x})^2(\frac{\sin ax}{ax})^2dx, a>0$ please?

I want to use Fourier transform, Fourier transform define as $$\mathcal{F}[f(t)] = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}f(t)e^{ist}dt.$$

first, I write $$(\frac{\sin x}{x})^2(\frac{\sin ax}{ax})^2 = -\frac{e^{-2iax}}{8a^2x^4}-\frac{e^{2iax}}{8a^2x^4}-\frac{e^{-2ix}}{8a^2x^4}-\frac{e^{2ix}}{8a^2x^4}+\frac{e^{2iax-2ix}}{16a^2x^4}+\frac{e^{2iax+2ix}}{16a^2x^4}+\frac{e^{-2iax-2ix}}{16a^2x^4}+\frac{e^{2ix-2iax}}{16a^2x^4}+\frac{1}{4a^2x^4} (*)$$

then, I know $\mathcal{F}[\frac{1}{x}] = i\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2}}\mathrm{sign}(x)$, and $\mathcal{F}[f^{(n)}(x)] = (-is)^n\mathcal{F}[f(x)]$, so I get $\mathcal{F}[\frac{1}{x^4}] = (-is)^3\mathcal{F}[-\frac{1}{6x}] = \frac{s^3}{6}\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2}}\mathrm{sign}(s)$. Now I use $$\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\frac{1}{x^4}e^{isx}dx = \mathcal{F}[\frac{1}{x^4}] = \frac{s^3}{6}\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2}}\mathrm{sign}(s),$$

so $$\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\frac{1}{x^4}e^{isx}dx = \frac{\pi s^3}{6}\mathrm{sign}(s).$$

Let $s = -2a$ and so on, I compute all the parts of (*). The result is same as Mathematica gives.

I use $\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\frac{1}{x^4}e^{isx}dx = \frac{\pi s^3}{6}\mathrm{sign}(s)$, but I know the integral can not converge, so how to fix it please?

Comment: Have you tried using $\int f^\ast g dx =\int\tilde{f}^\ast \tilde{g} dk$?

Comment: Just for your curiosity : if you enjoy sine and cosine integrals, there is closed form expression for $$\int(\frac{\sin ax}{ax})^2(\frac{\sin bx}{bx})^2dx$$

Comment: @J.G. Thank you. I know the convolution theorem, but I do not know how to use it here. I try $\mathcal{F}[\frac{\sin x}{x}] = \frac{1}{2}\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2}} (\mathrm{sign}(1-s)+\mathrm{sign}(s+1)),\mathcal{F}[\frac{\sin ax}{ax}] = \frac{\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2}}(\mathrm{sign}(a-s)+\mathrm{sign}(a+s))}{2a}$, then as $s\to0$, $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}(\frac{\sin x}{x})^2(\frac{\sin ax}{ax})^2e^{isx}dx=\mathcal{F}[\frac{\sin x}{x}]\ast\mathcal{F}[\frac{\sin x}{x}]\ast\mathcal{F}[\frac{\sin ax}{ax}]\ast\mathcal{F}[\frac{\sin ax}{ax}]$, but I think it is too complicated for me.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici Thank you, I am not sure I can do it myself, but I will try, Thank you.

Comment: @xunitc. Don't try ! This was a problem I worked years ago (it took me a long time to solve the antiderivative and to identify the conditions for the integral from $-\infty$ to $\infty$).